# ASP.NET MVC Repository and Controller Error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error message whenever I try to go to my OrderHistory page.

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult History(Int32)' in 'Mis324Assignments.Controllers.MusicController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult History(int Id)
    {
        return View(mor.GetHistory(Id));
    }
```

This is my Repository:

```
public List<MusicHistoryModel> GetHistory(int custID)
{
    using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(connectString))
    {
        string sql = @"SELECT OI.OrderId, OI.ASIN, OI.Qty, OI.Title,    OI.Artist, OI.Price, O.OrderDate
                     FROM tblOrders as O join tblOrderItems as OI on O.OrderId = OI.OrderId
                     Where O.CustId = @custID";
        List<MusicHistoryModel> history = db.Query<MusicHistoryModel>(sql,new { custID }).ToList();
        return history;
    }
}
```

This is my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Mis324Assignments.Models.MusicHistoryModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "History";
    Layout = "~/Views/Music/_3ColLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Order History</h2>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{



    <div class="row" style="padding:4px;">

        <div class="col-md-2">      
                <img src="http://images.amazon.com/images//P@(item.ASIN).01._SCTHUMBZZZ_V1115763748_.jpg"
                     class='productImage' style="margin:0 0 5px 10px;"  />

        </div>
      @item.OrderID
       @item.OrderDate
        @item.title
        @item.artist
        @item.price
        @item.qty


    </div>
}
```

This is my ActionLink that redirects to the History View:

```
   <form action="~/Music/History" method="post" class="enhancement">

         <input type="submit" value="Order History*" /><br />

     </form>
```

I am passing in an int id in my controller and it is using that int id as the custID to get information from my repository. I dont know why the error message is saying I am not passing anything into the int id parameter

Comment: Could you share your view implementation where you are calling History action?

Comment: I mean, your Actionlink from where you are redirecting to History page

Comment: I may simply be missing it, but where in your form (with the action="~/Music/History") are you passing the id? Is that your entire form?

Comment: I figured it out!!! ON my Action link I did not pass in the CustID parameter. That is why it did not get any id parameters!

Comment: Your ID is not transferred properly. You should open `network` and inspect request message to see what is passed to controller. I cannot see from your code what you exactly passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking at your view implementation, it seems that you are not passing id in the History action which is needed by your History Action.

You can pass id as your parameter in following way :

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("History", "Music",
           new { Id= your_id_should_be_here }, FormMethod.Post, new{  @class="enhancement"})
{
       <input type="submit" value="Order History*" /><br />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer submitted already put it as comment not as answer.

Answer (score -2):

I figured it out!!! ON my Action link I did not pass in the CustID parameter. That is why it did not get any id parameters!